# Animation is delayed when firing observer in the same function

Tags: ios, swift

I have a button in a child VC that, when pressed, fires an observer that's received in the parent VC. I'm trying to add animation code to this function, but the animation only seems to run after a delay. Removing the notification code removes the delay.

In the child:

```
@IBAction func myButtonAction(_ sender: Any) {

UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.1, animations: {
     self.myButton.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 0.95, y: 0.95)
})

let myNotification = Notification.Name(rawValue: "myApp.myNotification")
NotificationCenter.default.post(name: myNotification, object: nil)
}
```

And in the parent:

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(childButtonPressed), name: myNotification, object: nil)

@objc func childButtonPressed() {
// (lots of UI code, including some that makes changes in the child VC)
}
```

I tried replacing the observer with a delegate to no avail. Any ideas?

Comment: Too little code here to tell what's going on.. We can't reproduce it with just this code..

Comment: @Brandon I added some more, but not sure what's relevant. The func in the parent VC is very long so didn't want to overshare...

Answer (score 0):

Move the notification posting into the completion handler of the animation.

```
@IBAction func myButtonAction(_ sender: Any) {
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.1, animations: {
         self.myButton.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 0.95, y: 0.95)
    }) { _ in
        let myNotification = Notification.Name(rawValue: "myApp.myNotification")
        NotificationCenter.default.post(name: myNotification, object: nil)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Matt. I tried that but the delay was just too noticeable. I just don't understand why the code running in the parent VC should have any effect on when the animation runs.

Comment: Well, as you've been told, you've given no information, so that's the best you're going to get.